# CopyFolder method reporting 'Path not found' for valid path

Tags: vbscript, copy

I'm trying to set up a script to check a bunch of users old profiles and copy the favourites folder if it exists, but the `CopyFolder` method is telling me 'Path not found', although it doesn't say if this is the destination or the source.

The portion of the code that is causing me troube is this -

```
objFSO.CopyFolder old_favourites_unc, new_favourites_unc, true
```

The full code is in this PasteBin - http://pastebin.com/w9yXuAQ1

I chack both the destination and the source for existence before the copy, and that is ok, so I'm a little lost as to what I am doing wrong. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Try with suffixing a backslash in destination folder. Check whether the path has blank space also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the error with source folder.

if the source does not contain wildcards then destination folder is created automatically if not exist.

Comment: Many thanks, I've changed to `objFSO.CopyFolder old_favourites_unc & "*.*", new_favourites_unc, true`, and this has got rid of the error. However, all it is copying is the subfolders and their files, but not the files in the Favourites folder. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Add a backslash just before *.*

Comment: Before the `"*.*"`? So that becomes `"\*.*"`? I already have a backslash on the end of the `old_favourites_unc` (and `new_favourites_unc`) string, although adding it causes no error and gives the same results.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I was being a fool - added `objFSO.CopyFile old_favourites_unc & "\*.*", new_favourites_unc, true` to the script, so now I have one line to copy files, and another to copy folders (and their contents). Working fine, thanks for your help.

Comment: the same I was thinking to suggest.